# Firestore rule: match top level collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Setup:

- My top collection is named `users`
- Each `user` is named for their unique ID, `uid`
- I want to make a rule so that no matter what document or sub-collection is being accessed, if it will compare `uid` to the name of current `user` in users to allow

Current attempt:

- Note that this WORKS for top level `documents`, but as soon as I try to work with a sub-collection within that user, it fails
- If it matters, there will be 7 named sub-collections that are always the same between users

  ```
  rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /users/{user} {
        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth.uid != null;
        }

        allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == user
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Any help would be appreciated. I think I need to add some ** somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) to match all documents in all subcollection under the top-level collection.

```
    match /users/{user}/{everything=**} {
      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth.uid != null;
      }
      allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == user
    }
```

In rules version 2, recursive wildcards match 0 or more path segments.